# After removing #s from $1,a,a^2,...,a^n, (a>2)$, we divide the remaining numbers into two groups. Prove that the two groups can't have the same sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

After removing numbers from the following $n+1$ numbers, $1,a,a^2,...,a^n, (a>2)$, we divide the remaining numbers into two groups. Prove that the two groups can't have the same sum.

I don't know how to start on this; I was considering induction but I don't know if that's plausible. Could someone help me out?

Comment: If a is an integer you can show it pretty easily with the basis representation theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a>2$, $$a^n>\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^i$$  Therefore, whichever of the two sets contains the element with the largest exponent (among the terms that were not thrown out) must be the larger of the two sets.

Comment: what if n is negative?

Comment: The statement seems to imply that you are counting up to $n$.  If you were counting down, then it would be equivalent to a problem where you were counting up and the the base would be $\frac1a$, which would be less than 2.